# How do you sum all the numbers from 1 to 20?

Tags: python-3.x

Using python 3, how would you change this code to print the sum of all numbers from 1 to 20?

```
n = 20
i=0
sum = 0
for i in range (1,n+1):
    sum =+ i
    i = i+1
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way I can think about is:

```
sum(range(1, 21))  # includes 20
```

You can also use a loop:

```
s = 0
for i in range(21):
    s += i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 20
# this isn't needed, the for loop sets i: i = 0
sum = 0
for i in range (1, n+1):
    sum += i
    # Remove this line: i = i+1
    # for i in range already increments i
print(sum)
```

You shouldn't use the variable name `sum` because there is already a builtin function `sum` which you can even use instead.

Comment: If I wanted to change this to a while loop how would I format it? while i<21?

Comment: set i to 1. while i <= n: sum += i pretty much